# RESTfully checking for resource availability

Tags: rest, http-method

Assume, I have a REST resource with users and I need to check, whether a username already exists or not (and thus can be registered on the front end).

From my feeling, a clean RESTful approach for doing so would be to use a HEAD request on the username to check, such as:

```
HEAD /api/users/mary
```

And returning either a status `200` (username exists), or `404` (username does not exist). The problem I'm facing now: I'm performing a REST request via JavaScript, whether a user name already exists, like so:

```
$http.head('/api/users/' + username)
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         // username is taken
     })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         // username is free
     });
```

Now, Safari browser (and supposedly other browsers as well), are logging an error, in case a non-existing user it hit (i.e. `404` is returned from API):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Although a normal end user would usually not see the console, I've been thinking whether my approach in general is acceptable, or I should go for a different solution. Another idea I came up with is to use a `204` status (`No Content`) instead of the `404`, but that feels less 'explicit'.

Any different advice or suggestions welcome!

Comment: I think your approach is totally acceptable, and here too: http://www.pragmaticapi.com/2013/02/14/restful-patterns-for-the-head-verb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should leave the 404 error for `HEAD /api/users/mary`, but if you want to avoid the console log, you could create a different service that returns a resource that tells you if a the user exists or not.